# Broad word covering preferences and dispositions

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a broad word to cover preferences and dispositions, such as 'I'll work on weekends' or 'I don't mind scut work'.

As you may have guessed, it's to phrase a question on a job application form, which is currently phrased as 'Is there a reason why we should hire you that you’ve not had a chance to tell us about in the CV or application forms? For instance, skills and experience relevant to the roles you’re applying to.'

I realise it may be hard to find such a word; I only need a word to use in the above question that will elicit a broader range of reasons than just those related to 'skills and experience'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to elicit a broader range of reasons using a single word may fail; but by adding several words – such as  *[proclivities](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proclivity)*, *[interests](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interest)*, *[preferences](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preference#Noun)* – you can signal that you are asking for a broader rationale than otherwise:

> For instance, skills, experience, proclivities, interests, preferences related to the roles you’re applying for.

Comment: Proclivities is a good word.

Answer (score 1):

Are there additional reasons
why we should hire you that 
you’ve not included in your CV 
or application forms? For instance,
do you have skills and relevant
experience in the roles you are 
applying for, and are you amenable to,
for example, working weekends and
doing occasional scut work?